# Adding wininet.lib to qt

Tags: qt, visual-c++

Ive spent all day trying to get this to work. Someone plz tell me how to add the wininet library to my project in QT. I tried selecting it in the add library option and it wouldnt accept. Using gnu-gcc compiler. I got it to work on codeblocks but not QT

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using External Lib/DLLs in Qt Creator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858399/using-external-lib-dlls-in-qt-creator)

Comment: Do you want to add it in QtCreator? What do you mean by "it wouldnt accept" ?