# subdirs template in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to create project structure like below

```
test/
test.pro
build/
  build.pro
  main.cpp
gui/
  gui.pro
  mainwindow.h
  mainwindow.cpp
```

My *test.pro* looks like this:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS = gui
CONFIG += ordered
SUBDIRS +=build
```

*build.pro*

```
TEMPLATE = app
QT += core gui
SOURCES += main.cpp
LIBS += -L../gui
```

*gui.pro*

```
TEMPLATE  = lib

SOURCES += \
   mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += \
   mainwindow.h
```

*mainwindow.cpp*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(){}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){}
```

*mainwindow.h*

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
   public:
     MainWindow();
     ~MainWindow();
 };

 #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "gui/mainwindow.h" //error

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    //MainWindow w;
    //w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

I got an error during compilation:

```
../../test/build/main.cpp:2:25: error: gui/gui.h: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Thanks bruno.
I changed the line:

```
#include "gui/mainwindow.h"
```

to

```
#include "../gui/mainwindow.h"
```

But now I have error like below:

```
undefined reference to `MainWindow::MainWindow()' 
undefined reference to `MainWindow::~MainWindow()'
```

My *mainwindow.cpp* file looks like below:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{}
```

How should I add a *mainwindow.h* file to *mainwindow.cpp*??

Answer (score 1):

When I changed *build.pro* file to:

```
TEMPLATE = app
QT += core gui

SOURCES += main.cpp

LIBS += -L../gui/debug -lgui
```

application exited with code -1073741515.

Maybe the path in *libs* section is wrong?

Below files tree generated by qt:

```
test/
  test.pro
  build/
    build.pro
    main.cpp
  gui/
    gui.pro
    mainwindow.h
    mainwindow.cpp

test-build-desktop/
  Makefile
  build/
    debug/
    release/
    Makefile
    Makefile.Debug
    Makefile.Release
  gui/
    debug/
      gui.dll
      libgui.a
      mainwindow.o
    release/
    Makefile
    Makefile.Debug
    Makefile.Release
```

I checked the exe file by *Dependency Walker*: 
[LINK to image](http://grover.waw.pl/forum/gui_lib.jpg)

Comment: I've created a project with a tree equal to yours and all is working for me. I just needed to change the include directive and the LIBS section of the .pro file.

Comment: Only one last thing; when running your app, don't forget to place the gui.dll in the some directory as the .exe of your application or in a directory in the PATH. The same should be said about the qtcored4.dll and qtguid4.dll

Comment: Everything is working OK. The application works correctly. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
test/
test.pro
build/
  build.pro
  main.cpp
gui/
  gui.pro
  mainwindow.h
  mainwindow.cpp
```

There is no file named `gui.h` in `gui` directory - causing the error.

**EDIT**

May be you wanted `gui/mainwindow.h` to include?

Answer (score 0):

> error: gui/gui.h: No such file or directory

That's because there is no such file in that directory. :)

There are only 3 files in that directory 
  `gui.pro`
  `mainwindow.h` and
  `mainwindow.cpp`.

I think you wanted to include `"gui/mainwindow.h"`, right?

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know what I'm doing wrong?
>   When I comment out #include
>   "gui/mainwindow.h" then everything is
>   OK.

I think the problem is in your include directive.
Try changing it to

```
#include "../gui/mainwindow.h"
```

> When the preprocessor finds an
>   `#include` directive it replaces it by the entire content of the specified
>   file. There are two ways to specify a
>   file to be included:
>
> `#include "file"`
>   `#include <file>`
>
> The only difference between both
>   expressions is the places
>   (directories) where the compiler is
>   going to look for the file. In the
>   first case where the file name is
>   specified between double-quotes, the
>   file is searched first in the same
>   directory that includes the file
>   containing the directive. In case that
>   it is not there, the compiler searches
>   the file in the default directories
>   where it is configured to look for the
>   standard header files. If the file
>   name is enclosed between
>   angle-brackets <> the file is searched
>   directly where the compiler is
>   configured to look for the standard
>   header files. Therefore, standard
>   header files are usually included in
>   angle-brackets, while other specific
>   header files are included using
>   quotes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4%28VS.80%29.aspx

Edited:

Now for the undefined reference error.
You need to change your build.pro file.

Change:

```
LIBS += -L../gui
```

to something like

```
LIBS += -L../gui/debug -lgui
```

(the path ../gui/debug works for me because that is the place where the lib "gui" is located)

The idea is that you have to separate the directory where the library is located from the library name (without the extension and without any 'lib' prefix).

See this question here:
[Adding external library into Qt Creator project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/adding-external-library-into-qt-creator-project)