# unable to use aes files of openssl in qt creator

Tags: openssl, aes

I am trying to include AES header file an `#include <openssl/aes.h>` in Qt4 Creator but while compiling its giving error as **`openssl/aes.h: No such file or directory`**. Please tell me how to include to this file so that I can use AES functions in my program?

Answer (score 1):

If this is on Linux, add the following into your `.pro` file:

```
PKGCONFIG += openssl
```

It will handle all necessary header paths, compile-linker options and the libraries.

And make sure you have the `openssl-devel` package installed in your system.

If this is on Windows, see the duplicate above.