# Openssl binaries dont have lib file or include headers for Qt

Tags: c++, qt, openssl

Following this easy answer to Openssl in Qt, I run the installer.
[How to Include OpenSSL in a Qt project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681012/how-to-include-openssl-in-a-qt-project)

The openssl folder I get has no lib folder or include folder.
Why

Edit: I had installed the light version not meant for developers -_-

Comment: Maybe you installed the 3MB light version and not the one for developers which is around 37MB to 43MB.

Comment: Ohh.. Yes you are right.. Thats so silly they recommend the light version.

Thankyou a lot