# How to fix qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed error in QT

Tags: c++, qt, openssl

I am trying to learn how to network using Qt, and I recently got stuck with one of their examples, "The twitter timeline example", it keeps on giving me this error,"", after surfing the net, I found out that it is probably because I do not have openssl installed. Can someone please tell me what I am doing

After following this example and several others, [How to Include OpenSSL in a Qt project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681012/how-to-include-openssl-in-a-qt-project) , the problem remains unchanged.

this is my .pro file

```
QT = core widgets network networkauth
requires(qtConfig(tableview))
CONFIG -= app_bundle
LIBS += -LC:/OpenSSL-Win64/lib -lubsec
HEADERS += \
    twitter.h \
    twittertimelinemodel.h
INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenSSL-Win64/include
SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    twitter.cpp \
    twittertimelinemodel.cpp

FORMS += \
    twitterdialog.ui

# install
target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES]/oauth/twittertimeline
INSTALLS += target
```

> qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket::connectToHostEncrypted: TLS initialization failed
>   qt.networkauth.replyhandler: TLS initialization failed
>   The error it keeps on returning.

Comment: can you and download the binary files and extract the files where your executable is located. https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/.

Comment: did that now, I am still getting the same error

Comment: can you double check how you are compiling your executable. make sure your you are not mixing libraries if you compile for 64 make sure the other dlls are also compiled as 64 bit. i compiled on my machine with visual studio 2015 x64 with just the default settings and it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot, The problem was due to the fact that I had tried a lot of things without removing them, copied the code to a different project and tried it out, it works. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hello, I think I am still in need of a little help, I am trying to write an app that uses the google search api, and I have tried using the same approach but the error isn't leaving. In addition to the "QJsonParseError::IllegalValue"

Comment: QSslSocket::supportsSsl() and I used this function to check whether system supports ssl, got a false