# Can't add external package in Qt

Tags: qt, network-programming, websocket

I'm newbie in C++ programming. I started from Qt 5.0.1. I need to use WebSockets from: https://code.google.com/p/tufao/ but I don't have MinGW installation so I googled that I can create Qt library project, include these source files and build static library. So I did it:

```
QT       += network
QT       -= gui
TARGET = tufao
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += staticlib
INCLUDEPATH = src src/priv
SOURCES += \
    src/websocket.cpp \
    src/url.cpp \
    src/simplesessionstore.cpp \
    src/sessionstore.cpp \
    src/querystring.cpp \
    src/httpserverresponse.cpp \
    src/httpserverrequestrouter.cpp \
    src/httpserverrequest.cpp \
    src/httpserver.cpp \
    src/httppluginserver.cpp \
    src/httpfileserver.cpp \
    src/headers.cpp \
    src/abstractmessagesocket.cpp \
    src/abstracthttpserverrequesthandler.cpp \
    src/priv/tcpserverwrapper.cpp \
    src/priv/rfc1123.cpp \
    src/priv/rfc1036.cpp \
    src/priv/reasonphrase.cpp \
    src/priv/http_parser.c \
    src/priv/asctime.cpp

HEADERS += \
    src/websocket.h \
    src/url.h \
    src/tufao_global.h \
    src/simplesessionstore.h \
    src/sessionstore.h \
    src/sessionsettings.h \
    src/session.h \
    src/querystring.h \
    src/ibytearray.h \
    src/httpsserver.h \
    src/httpserverresponse.h \
    src/httpserverrequestrouter.h \
    src/httpserverrequest.h \
    src/httppluginserver.h \
    src/httpfileserver.h \
    src/headers.h \
    src/abstractmessagesocket.h \
    src/abstracthttpserverrequesthandlerfactory.h \
    src/abstracthttpserverrequesthandler.h \
    src/priv/websocket.h \
    src/priv/url.h \
    src/priv/tcpserverwrapper.h \
    src/priv/simplesessionstore.h \
    src/priv/sessionstore.h \
    src/priv/rfc1123.h \
    src/priv/rfc1036.h \
    src/priv/reasonphrase.h \
    src/priv/httpsserver.h \
    src/priv/httpserverresponse.h \
    src/priv/httpserverrequestrouter.h \
    src/priv/httpserverrequest.h \
    src/priv/httpserver.h \
    src/priv/httppluginserver.h \
    src/priv/httpfileserver.h \
    src/priv/http_parser.h \
    src/priv/cryptography.h \
    src/priv/asctime.h
unix:!symbian {
    maemo5 {
        target.path = /opt/usr/lib
    } else {
        target.path = /usr/lib
    }
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

After build, I get `libtufao.a`. So next step is to test it. I created simple test project and added this library by clicking Add library -> external -> static. Open dialog can open only `.lib` files so I changed `libtufao.a` to `libtufao.lib`:

```
QT       += core gui network
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets   
TARGET = sockettest
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../components/tufao-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MinGW_32bit-Release/release/ -llibtufao
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../components/tufao-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MinGW_32bit-Release/debug/ -llibtufao

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../components/tufao/src
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../components/tufao/src

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../components/tufao-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MinGW_32bit-Release/release/libtufao.lib
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../components/tufao-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MinGW_32bit-Release/debug/libtufao.lib
```

But when I try to build this test project I get compiler error:

> undefined reference to
>   `*imp*__ZN5Tufao9WebSocket13connectToHostERK12QHostAddresstRK10QByteArrayRKNS_7HeadersE'
>   collect2.exe:-1:
>
> error: ld returned 1 exit status

Can anyone help me?

Regards

**EDIT:**
Problem solved by adding all sources into my dest project and in `.pro` file I added `DEFINES += TUFAO_LIBRARY`. Now everything is compiling fine.

Comment: Please, answer your question andmark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Adding external library into Qt Creator project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/adding-external-library-into-qt-creator-project)

The linker can't find the implementation of `WebSocket::connectToHost`, so you need to link the library that has that function in it.

In your .pro file, add

```
LIBS += "path/to/lib/libname"
```

Or if it is in your library paths already, you may be able to put

```
LIBS += -lmylibname
```

So I think for you, might be

```
LIBS += -llibtufao
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Still same error. Maybe problem is in my library project which compile this lib (first code in my post)?

Comment: ... and even if I add all these files into my test project I get houndred similar errors

Comment: the .a file is what the file type for a static library looks like on unix.  You can't just rename it to a .lib file (the static library for windows).  That is probably where you are having a problem.  What OS are you doing this on?

Comment: Hmm, I compiled this lib on Windows XP 32 bit. Project created by QT Creator

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Shipped with QT installator (so MinGW? I'm newbie in C++). This is clean Windows XP virtual mashine, only QT Creator installed. I created new "library project" and added all websocket files

Comment: ... and I checked "Static linked library" when created this library project

Comment: So, I don't think you need to build this library from its source... Your options when downloading Qt 5.0.1 were Mingw or MSVS2010 as the compiler.  You can check this in Qt Creator > Tools > Options > Build and Run > Kits...  Looking at the downloads available for tufao, they have builds for both of these compilers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24982/discussion-between-phyatt-and-dibo)