# Linker error: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_rwlock_trywrlock@@GLIBC_2.2.5'

Tags: c++, qt, gcc4.7

I've been developing with CentOS, Qt 4.7, and GCC 4.4

I've just installed Red Hat Developer Toolset 1.1 which includes GCC 4.7.2, and at the end of `make`, I get an error

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../../bin/Solo: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_rwlock_trywrlock@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'pthread_rwlock_trywrlock@@GLIBC_2.2.5' is defined in DSO /lib64/libpthread.so.0 so try adding it to the linker command line
/lib64/libpthread.so.0: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm guessing that Qt threads is referencing to that. How can I fix it?

Comment: Does your command line for the compiler/linker contain `-pthread`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want to compile with `-pthread` which does more than just link with libpthread:

> Adds support for multithreading with the pthreads library.  This
>              option sets flags for both the preprocessor and linker.

Answer (score 5):

Read the note: try to add `/lib64/libpthread.so.0` into Makefile (`-lpthread` after `gcc` command, or `/lib64/libpthread.so.0` after `ld` (or after `gcc -shared`)), or something like `LIB += -lpthread` if there's such definition somewhere.

See also: [Adding external library into Qt Creator project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/adding-external-library-into-qt-creator-project) and http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/39144-How-to-add-a-lib-to-a-qt-project

Btw, post your Makefile, so somebody will be able to point to exact line.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to add `CONFIG += thread` to your `.pro` file.

Answer (score 1):

In my little laptop Linux (where I have a mixed bag of libraries),
I just had to add

```
LDFLAGS=-lpthread
```

AT THE END of the configure command arguments.

After that, make did its job perfectly (With the existing libraries).

Answer (score 0):

I received similar 'Linker error: undefined reference to symbol' errors attempting to compile and install Python-3.7.2 on FreeBSD 12.

```
/usr/bin/ld: error: undefined symbol: _Py_GetGlobalVariablesAsDict
/usr/bin/ld: error: undefined symbol: _PyCoreConfig_AsDict
/usr/bin/ld: error: undefined symbol: _PyMainInterpreterConfig_AsDict
```

Resolved by passing `LDFLAGS=-lpthread` directly to make of lang/python37 or by adding to `/etc/make.conf`.
If using portmaster to install/update use `-m` to pass the arguement to make e.g.`portmaster -a -m 'LDFLAGS=-lpthread'`