# How do you specify platform agnostic paths in a Qt .pro file?

Tags: qt, shared-libraries

I want to include a third party library by specifying it in my `INCLUDEPATH` in my .pro file. However, the library is installed in a different location on each platform (Windows, Mac, Linux).

How do I properly specify an `INCLUDEPATH` for a cross-platform application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this in your .pro file is to use LIBS += as seen in this other related stack overflow question at [Adding external library into Qt Creator project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/adding-external-library-into-qt-creator-project)