# WinSNMP wont link without explicit path?

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qt-creator

I'm using QtCreator with MinGW and cant seem to link to WinSNMP without specifying an explicit path.

I can easily link to Winsock:
LIBS += -lws2_32

If I try with WinSNMP the linker says it cant find the library?:
LIBS += LIBS += -lwsnmp32

If I link with the direct path, it works fine:
LIBS += C:\Qt\Tools\mingw48_32\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libwsnmp32.a

How do I link to WinSNMP without specifying a direct path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/adding-external-library-into-qt-creator-project

Comment: This is a system configuration error. The library is not in a place that's where libraries are sought out.

Comment: @David Heffernan I know I can link it directly. I mention this in my post. But, why does it need an absolute path but winsock doesn't?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit If it is a configuration error then why does winsock link directly as stated in my question?

Comment: @DaviddeBruyn: Because you didn't properly configure your system such that the library is on your search path. It's found when you provide an absolute location, because then the search path becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Why does it find libws2_32.a, which is in the same directory? For winsock I can go LIBS += -lws2_32, but the same thing doest work for libwsnmp32.a?

Comment: @DaviddeBruyn: Oh, you never said it was in the same directory!

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Sorry. That would have been too easy then ;) At this point I'm assuming that it isn't supported, but is rather provided "as is" for those who want to use it.