# Why my include of libraries in QT isn't correct?

Tags: qt, libraries

I have **3 libraries** that I have to use, of course I've got the header file associated for each one.
To include these libraries I write this in my `.pro` file :

```
LIBS += -L $$quote(C:/libs/ARINC825/lib/VC/amd64/) -larinc825
LIBS += -L $$quote(C:/libs/SDK/lib/VC/amd64/) -lntcan
LIBS += -L $$quote(C:/libs/SDK/lib/VC/amd64/) -lirigb
```

These libraries are for the **use of a CAN card**.

When I compile, the compilator can't find the functions associated to the first library : `-larinc825`

Here's an **error line** for example : `undefined reference to arincHandleOpen`

Can you explain me why my include fail ?

Thanks.

PS : **I did some research**, and try to use this topic [Adding external library into Qt Creator project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/adding-external-library-into-qt-creator-project) but it gives no result.

**EDIT** : I'm on **QT5**, I can use the **minWG** compiler or the VisualStudio 2010 compiler.

**EDIT2** : Don't know why, but this seems to works :

```
LOCATION1="C:\Program Files\ESD\CAN\ARINC825\lib\VC\i386"
INCLUDEPATH += "$$LOCATION1/include"
QMAKE_LIBDIR += "$$LOCATION1"
LIBS += -larinc825

LOCATION2="C:\Program Files\ESD\CAN\SDK\lib\VC\i386"
INCLUDEPATH += "$$LOCATION2/include"
QMAKE_LIBDIR += "$$LOCATION2"
LIBS += -lirigb -lntcan
```

Comment: which version of Qt are you using? Which compiler are you using? Which type of library do you want to include?

Comment: @Cool_Coder I just edit my post :)

Comment: ok so you want to static link a library right? i.e. .lib or .a?

Comment: .lib library, don't know the difference between static and dynamic :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are linking a `.lib` library specific to Windows platform here is what I have in my `.pro` file:

```
win32 {
    equals(BITNESS, 32)
    {
        LIBS += "C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP SDK\2.9\lib\x86\OpenCL.lib"
    }
    equals(BITNESS, 64)
    {
        LIBS += "C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP SDK\2.9\lib\x86_64\libOpenCL.a"
    }
}
```

MinGW has some problem with linking 64 bit libraries in `.lib` format.
So I suggest you to try to link the `.a` file.
After reading rubenvb's comment, it is clear that `MinGW` has a generic issue of not being able to link 64 bit libraries in `.lib` format. So if you want to link in 64 bit you **MUST** have a `.a` version of your library.

The `BITNESS` is a variable that is passed to `qmake` which is used to check if the build is for 32 bit or 64 bit.
You need to set these only once for your project.
Your project must be using 2 kits: 1 for the 32 bit compiler and other for the 64 bit compiler. You can set the `BITNESS` variable as follows:

```
DEFINES+="BITNESS=64"
```

This line should be added in the **Build steps** for `qmake`.
Similarly add `DEFINES+="BITNESS=32"` for 32 bit kit.

Comment: have you added the BITNESS variable in your kit?

Comment: Yes, but I don't have .a file, only .lib, and my system is on 64 bits.

Comment: so try with the .lib file instead and see if it works.

Comment: No, still can't find the functions

Comment: 64-bit static/import libraries can indeed not be linked by GNU ld (which is what MinGW uses). This is a general incompatibility and not related to OpenCL in any way. AMD's OpenCL SDK delivers a GNU ld `libopencl.a` for both architectures, so there should be no problem if you used [`-L` and `-l`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs) instead of dropping the full file path in the `LIBS` variable.

Comment: @Cool_Coder: Also, I suggest you use [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/18874/#92037) for your OpenCL linking... Until qmake gets a decent way to detect target architecture, you are indeed stuck with an extra define. You could of course just use `CONFIG += x86` when invoking qmake and just use the string `x86` as a test.

Comment: It is indeed the most elegant solution. But where are AMDAPPSDKinclude and AMDAPPSDKlib defined? My system environment only has AMDAPPSDK defined.