# Configuring Makefile to produce a .a library instead of a .lib

Tags: linux, makefile, libraries

I'm trying to compile a C library in a Linux Ubuntu environment (and that will be used by a Embedded Linux program), but when I do a `make` on it, I get a `.lib` instead of a `.a` file even thought it seems that there is no place in the Makefile that commands such a change (a would expect that compiling a library in Ubuntu would produce a `.a` file by default!).

What follows is the Makefile being used fro this library (the result now being `calculos.lib`):

### Makefile

```
#   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Name of the ARM GCC cross compiler & archiver
#   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ARM_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX = arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-
ARM_TOOLCHAIN_PATH = /re8k/linux-devkit
ARM_CC := $(ARM_TOOLCHAIN_PATH)/bin/$(ARM_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)gcc
ARM_AR := $(ARM_TOOLCHAIN_PATH)/bin/$(ARM_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)ar

# Get any compiler flags from the environment
ARM_CFLAGS = $(CFLAGS)
ARM_CFLAGS += -std=gnu99 \
-Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wall -Wno-trigraphs \
-fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -fno-omit-frame-pointer \
-c -O3
ARM_LDFLAGS = $(LDFLAGS)
ARM_LDFLAGS+=-lm -lpthread
ARM_ARFLAGS = rcs

#   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Name of the DSP C6RUN compiler & archiver
#   TI C6RunLib Frontend (if path variable provided, use it, otherwise assume 
#   the tools are in the path)
#   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
C6RUN_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX = c6runlib-
C6RUN_TOOLCHAIN_PATH = $(ARM_TOOLCHAIN_PATH)/c6run
C6RUN_CC := $(C6RUN_TOOLCHAIN_PATH)/bin/$(C6RUN_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)cc
C6RUN_AR := $(C6RUN_TOOLCHAIN_PATH)/bin/$(C6RUN_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX)ar

C6RUN_CFLAGS = -c -mt -O3
C6RUN_ARFLAGS = rcs

#   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   List of lib source files
#   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
LIB_SRCS := calculos.c
LIB_DSP_OBJS := $(LIB_SRCS:%.c=dsp_obj/%.o)
LIB_OBJS := $(LIB_DSP_OBJS:%.o=%.lib)

all: dsp_obj/.created
    $(C6RUN_CC) $(C6RUN_CFLAGS) -o $(LIB_DSP_OBJS) $(LIB_SRCS) -DUSE_DSP;
    $(C6RUN_AR) $(C6RUN_ARFLAGS) $(LIB_OBJS) $(LIB_DSP_OBJS);

all_host: dsp_obj/.created
    gcc -c -o $(LIB_DSP_OBJS) $(LIB_SRCS);
    ar rcs $(LIB_OBJS) $(LIB_DSP_OBJS);

dsp_obj/.created:
    @mkdir -p dsp_obj
    @touch dsp_obj/.created

clean:
    rm -rf dsp_obj;

distclean: clean
```

So the question is: **how should I configure my Makefile so it will produce a `.a` file instead of a `.lib`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that causes the `.lib` extension is `LIB_OBJS := $(LIB_DSP_OBJS:%.o=%.lib)` which replaces `.o` in each file in `LIB_DSP_OBJS` with `.lib`.

Change the `.lib` to `.a` in that line and see if that does what you need.

Comment: thanks for the reply, Etan. Now looking at the file I ask myself: How couldn't I see that? \o/ Guess I came too quickly to SO this time =T Its a pity that my real problem persists (qmake's LIBS is not being able to recognize the library even when its in the right format)

Comment: Is that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25728411/qmake-not-finding-some-existing-libraries?

Comment: yeah, thats the link where I'm facing the 'real problem'!