# How to use FMOD tools in QT Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, api, qt-creator, fmod

I want to insert FMOD dll file and header file in my QT Project.

I use QT Creator and I don't know how can I add FMOD api.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You should add headers and libs to your .pro file (look at [Adding external library into Qt Creator project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/adding-external-library-into-qt-creator-project)). So in this case it will be something like that:

```
INCLUDEPATH += -"C:\Program Files\FMOD SoundSystem\FMOD Programmers API Win32\api\inc\"
LIBS += "C:\Program Files\FMOD SoundSystem\FMOD Programmers API Win32\api\lib\  -libfmodex"
```

Comment: Maybe using some environment variable in order to specify library path.