# How do i create a .lib or .a file in Qt c++?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, shared-libraries

I am new to C++ and i am starting to develop with Qt framework.
Actually i'm enjoying but i'm getting some trouble adding libs to my projects.
I'm used to C# where when i want to use some lib, i just download a dll file, add reference to it and its done.
For what i understand until now, c++ is not that easy.
I read that i've to compile the source code and generate a .lib or .a file, but i dont see how to do it.
I saw this page: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html but dont understand how to do it.
It tells to run "configure" command that is not recognized by windows. (probably something is missing)
At this moment, i'm interessing to import a pcaplib to my project. (this one: http://www.tcpdump.org/).
I downloaded the files, but instead of getting a .lib file i get a .gz package with a bunch of files.
Can someone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Wait, it sounds like you got Qt working already, right? If so the first link is irrelevant. It's for building Qt yourself instead of using the pre-built binaries they provide.

Comment: Actually I find it highly unclear where your actual problem lies. As for building libpcap for windows look inside the `README.Win32` file of the .gz package. It points to https://www.winpcap.org/install/default.htm for prebuilt binaries in a installer. Or opening the projectfile at `winpcap\wpcap\prj\wpcap.prj`. Following the instructions there should probably work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding external library into Qt Creator project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/adding-external-library-into-qt-creator-project)