# add libusb library to Qt project

Tags: qt, libusb

I am trying to add libusb library from https://github.com/libusb/libusb/releases/download/v1.0.22/libusb-1.0.22.7z
to my qt project can anyone  help me ,I can't figure out how to add this library to my project

Comment: Windows will block accesses to devices that are already managed by another driver, so libusb is unlikely to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding external library into Qt Creator project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/adding-external-library-into-qt-creator-project)

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

Edit `file.pro`:

```
LIBS += -lusb-1.0
```

Edit your source `fileHeader.h`:

```
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
```