# How to install and add libpng to my Qt project on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, libpng

I need to use libpng for my coursework with Qt. But I don't know how to install it and use with Qt on Windows.

### Try to install with MinGw

Firstly, I've downloaded libpng and zlib from official site. Then I've tried to install it with MinGw, *./configure CFLAGS='-O2' CXXFLAGS='-O2' --prefix=/mingw* this command executes perfectly, but then I got a problem. After typing *make* and *make install* I've got following issue. I don't know how to fix it and what it actually mean, because I've never faced errors from makefiles.

### Try to install via application

I've found an application for installing libpng on windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libpng.htm. And it worked, I've installed a library, got my *lib* files and headers. Then I went to my Qt project, and added a library, by pointing path to lib file and path to headers. Now I'm including *png.h* in my class and things seems to go well, until I try to use some functions. Qt writes something like this ***No mathcing function for call to png_sig_cmp***. But more interestingly, that it actually don't show errors when I use variable types from library, for example *png_byte*.

```
//messege from MinGw after typing make and make install
rm -f pnglibconf.c pnglibconf.tf[45]
gawk -f ./scripts/options.awk out=pnglibconf.tf4 version=search\
            ./pngconf.h ./scripts/pnglibconf.dfa\
            ./pngusr.dfa  1>&2
gawk -f ./scripts/options.awk out=pnglibconf.tf5 pnglibconf.tf4 1>&2
options.awk: bad line (10): com
make: *** [pnglibconf.c] Error 1
```

I expect to install library on my disk and be able to include it in other projects in other IDE fast.

Comment: Why was not there png support from the beginning? I use Qt for many years and never tried to install that manually. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimageformats-index.html

Comment: @AlexanderV this is my course work and this is a stupid restriction on using libpng and not using Qt clases for image work.

Comment: I am unsure why Qt then complains about the function missing while it can only be your own code that misses it. Otherwise you should explore https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/third-party-libraries.html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/adding-external-library-into-qt-creator-project Maybe the last one is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For your build problem  Google search yields: https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/issues/1054#issuecomment-335846694 .
2. Suppose you built not libpng, but libcurl as I did a while ago with mingw compiler,
   then to use libcurl within your Qt project file do:

```
win32 {

    ## Windows common build here

     win32-g++:contains(QMAKE_HOST.arch, x86_64):{
        message("x86_64 build")
        INCLUDEPATH += C:\QT64\Lib64\curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw64\include
        LIBS += C:\Qt64\Lib64\curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw64\lib64\libcurldll.a
        # Win64 specific build here

     } else {
             message("x86 build")
             INCLUDEPATH += C:\QT\Lib\curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw32\include
             LIBS += C:\Qt\Lib\curl-7.40.0-devel-mingw32\lib\libcurldll.a
             #Win32 specific build here
            }
}
```

Comment: I've successfuly installed library, but now I have another issue. When I trie to make my project I got a following warning: _warning lnk4098 defaultlib libcmtd conflicts with use of other libs; use /nodefaultlib:library_. I've searhced on Internet for the solution, but none of them helped me out.

Comment: Check this: https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/69006-Qt-Creator-error-NODEFAULTLIB-library-No-such-file-or-directory?s=fed13459e59a4f9556d23da256074c04&p=301515#post301515