# How to include libs into Qt project?

Tags: c++, winapi, qmake

I'm trying to figure out how to use the `winapi` [SetWindowSubclass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-setwindowsubclass)

On a non-Qt project under MSVC I can use the API by including:

```
#include <commctrl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")
```

I have been trying for hours unsuccessfully to link this lib on my project. I have found these `comctl32.lib` on my machine:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQhN3.png

I tried adding into **`.pro`**:

`LIBS += -comctl32`

`LIBS += -comctl32.lib` => `error: unrecognized command-line option '-comctl32'`

`LIBS += comctl32`

`LIBS += comctl32.lib` => `error: cannot find comctl32: No such file or directory`

I copied the one from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22000.0\um\arm64`
and past it on a new folder under `C:\Qt\Libs`

`LIBS += C:\Qt\Libs` => `error: cannot find C:\Qt\Libs: Permission denied`

`LIBS += -L"C:\Qt\Libs"` => this didn't throw any of the errors from above, but now I have these compiler error:

[image]

**.pro**

```
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
CONFIG += c++17

LIBS += -L"C:\Qt\Libs"
#win32:QMAKE_FLAGS += -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22000.0\um\arm64"
#win32:LIBS += cm-comctl32.lib

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

RESOURCES += \
    rcdata.qrc
```

**.h**

```
#include <commctrl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib") // <- warning: Unkown pragma ignored
```

**.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    SetWindowSubclass((HWND)ui->tabWidget->find(0), ButtonProc, 0, (DWORD_PTR)&ui);
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
}
```

Using Qt Creator 8.0.1

Qt 6.3.1, compiler MinGW 64-bit

Comment: `#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")` is a msvc pragma.

Comment: Should it be `LIBS += -lcomctl32` for MinGW?

Comment: @drescherjm with `-lcomctl32` compiled, i cant thank you enough, could you make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `LIBS += -lcomctl32` for your compiler instead of the several other options you tried. This related question has additional detail: [Adding external library into Qt Creator project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718447/adding-external-library-into-qt-creator-project)